# How to change docker lxc/cgroup configuration at runtime

Tags: lxc, docker, cgroup

I would like to change docker lxc/cgroup settings while a container is running. As an example, if I launch a container like this:

```
docker run --lxc-conf="lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = 0" ...
```

How do I adjust the setting to "lxc.cgroup.cpuset.cpus = 1" without stopping and starting the container.